# Best way to secure KeyVault settings in IConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-keyvault

Currently we are working on encrypting sensitive data to the database.
The key for encryption and decryption is stored in Azure KeyVault and imported into IConfiguration using AddAzureKeyVault.

We did notice however, that the injected config with the key is still readable in memory.
Is there a way to encrypt/protect (using dataprotector) values when added using AddAzureKeyVault?

(We use a seperate webserver and database server)

Comment: Which data do you want to protect, and against whom? Someone who has access to your server's memory can do anything they want.

Comment: Where is your database? Is it a service provided by Azure? or you have your own database in a VM in Azure?

Comment: The database is on 1 of our own VM's. We only use Azure fot the KeyVault

Comment: @Codecaster: we want to protect the data from any hacker that gets access to memorydumps or pagefile. I know that this can be protected by using dataprotector api

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but this sounds like an XY problem. If a hacker can obtain a memory dump, and at that moment your database has the entire database (or a portion thereof) unencrypted in memory because it was queried, then what? Your application is also going to need to have the key in memory, in order to encrypt or decrypt. DataProtection APIs are for _storage_, not usage.

Comment: @CodeCaster: my web application and database are on seperate servers.
The data we encrypt is very sensitive.
The only way for a hacker to descrypt the data is when he has access to the key. The key is stored in memory on the server.

PS: I always had the impression that dataprotector should only be used for short-lived encryption and never for long-time encryption stored in databases

Comment: @CodeCaster: Following link explains why not to use dataprotector for long-term protection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/limited-lifetime-payloads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: No, that is not what that page says. And also, if your web server is compromised and its memory exposed to hackers, they still can't access your database. They have the key, but no connection to it. Also, if your web server happens to be rendering sensitive data for another user at that moment, it's readable in the dump. Again, it looks like you're barking up the wrong tree. Solving this problem isn't likely to make your system more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider not using a configuration?

If you do not want to keep the secret data in memory, you can just directly get a secret from key vault every time your app needs it.

By the way, I think rather than consider encrypting the configuration file, it is better to strengthen the security of the server. If a hacker accessed your server and could dump server memory, there would be no security at all.